# How to write integration test for filter in grails

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-filters

I have written one filter rule which I want to test using grails integration tests.
Filter is

```
invalidAccess(controller: "home") {
    before = {
            redirect(controller: "newHome", action: "index")
            return false
    }
}
```

I have followed this link to write the integration test 
http://ldaley.com/post/392153102/integration-testing-grails-filters

It returns result as false But gives

> null for redirectedUrl

instead of newHome & index method url.
What am I missing here?

```
import grails.util.GrailsWebUtil

class MyFilterTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    def filterInterceptor
    def grailsApplication
    def grailsWebRequest

    def request(Map params, controllerName, actionName) {
        grailsWebRequest = GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(grailsApplication.mainContext)
        grailsWebRequest.params.putAll(params)
        grailsWebRequest.controllerName = controllerName
        grailsWebRequest.actionName = actionName
        filterInterceptor.preHandle(grailsWebRequest.request, grailsWebRequest.response, null)
    }

    def getResponse() {
        grailsWebRequest.currentResponse
    }

    def testFilterRedirects() {
        def result = request( someParameter: "2", "home", "index")
        assertFalse result
        assertTrue response.redirectedUrl.endsWith(/* something */)
    }

}
```

Comment: Provided link is more than 4 yr. old. Try grails document: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/testing.html#unitTestingFilters

Comment: I already tried writing unit tests as given in this document. But the problem is there are many calls to service classes & it doesn't provide how to mock those service class. I tried the way how we do it in controller classes or using defineBeans but doesn't help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try `unit testing` and need to mock some services then you can mock like:

```
@TestFor(SomethingToTest)
@Mock([FirstService, SecondService])
class SomethingToTestSpec extends Specification {
```

and you want `integration test` then try following test

```
import grails.util.GrailsWebUtil
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class MyFilterIntegrationTests {

    def filterInterceptor
    def grailsApplication
    def grailsWebRequest

    @Before
    void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    void testFilterRedirects() {
        def result = request("person", "index", someParameter: "2")
        assert !result
        assert response.redirectedUrl.endsWith('/auth/index')
    }

    def getResponse() {
        grailsWebRequest.currentResponse
    }

    def request(Map params, controllerName, actionName) {
        grailsWebRequest = GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(grailsApplication.mainContext)
        grailsWebRequest.params.putAll(params)
        grailsWebRequest.controllerName = controllerName
        grailsWebRequest.actionName = actionName
        filterInterceptor.preHandle(grailsWebRequest.request, grailsWebRequest.response, null)
    }
}
```

Ref# [Grails Integration Test Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736193/grails-integration-test-filter)

Comment: Yup. That unit tests answered worked for me. But integration test is still giving same issue.

Comment: Good to know that unit test works, as per grails doc. And for integration, I have tested with grails 2.3.9 and it is working for me.

Comment: I am using grails 2.2.4. It returns false which is fine but redirectedUrl is null.